# How Do you Properly Add An Image Control To Wordpress Customizer?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Wordpress admin customizer control is incomplete. How can I fix it?

My Code:

```
$wp_customize->add_setting('swag_header_media');
$wp_customize->add_control(new WP_Customize_Image_Control($wp_customize, 'swag_header_media', array(
    'label'            => 'Current Image Selection',
    'section'          => 'swag_header_media_section',
    'active_callback'  => 'header_show_image_selection_settings_callback',
    'settings'         => 'swag_header_media'
)));
```

The results are incomplete. I can select an image from the and the image show up in the frontend of the theme. However, the image selected does not show that it is being used in the control.

In other words(see screenshot), you can see the background image being used(phone), but it doesn't show that it being used in the admin customizer control. Its says "Current Image Selection", but it's empty with no buttons below it to change or remove it.

[image]

Comment: Is that your actual code? Because I tested it and it worked fine for me. Can you show the code for registering the customizer section and also the code for the `header_show_image_selection_settings_callback` function? Or maybe try with an empty `active_callback` (which defaults to `true`).

Comment: Tes, it is my actual code. The result is the same, whether I use the callback or not.

Comment: Well, perhaps deactivating plugins would help you identify the problem source. Try also the same code with a default theme - i.e. create a child theme with just `style.css` and `functions.php`, and the functions file, use that code.

Comment: I tried this code snippet with the Gutenberg Starter Starter theme and got the same result. Mind you, this is on a fresh install. https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg-starter-theme

Comment: So have you already tried the sample child themes? And even with those themes, you're still getting the same issue??

Answer (score 1):

When you inspect the page, is there any errors?

It is a bit hard to figure out with so little data.

Try this 'settings' => 'themename_theme_options[swag_header_media]',

Comment: Fresh install, no php errors, no errors on inspect, no console errors. I am at a loss. I tried your suggested code and the control no longer appears at all.

Comment: Have you reached out to the theme developer?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$wp_customize->add_setting('themename_theme_mods[swag_header_media]',array(
    //'default'           => 'image.jpg',
    //'capability'        => 'edit_theme_options',
    //'type'              => 'option'
));

$wp_customize->add_control(new WP_Customize_Image_Control($wp_customize, 'swag_header_media', array(
    'label'            => 'Current Image Selection',
    'section'          => 'swag_header_media_section',
    'active_callback'  => 'header_show_image_selection_settings_callback',
    'settings'         => 'themename_theme_mods[swag_header_media]'
)));
```

if that doesnt work,I suggest to change `swag_header_media` to other keyname. I suspect that key name might be used by other control/funtion too. So, try to add any 1 letter to that keyname, and see the result. Also, if you have any caching on site, turn it off.

also, the problem could be with `callback`,